# How can I delete everything after the next word matching a regular expression?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to delete all fields to the end of the line after a matching pattern and i want to print the next field to the pattern aswell.
There could be multiple patterns.

**Example:**

```
one two three four five six seven
robin mike luke jennifer jessie mark
...
```

**Patterns:**

```
two
jennifer
```

**Output:**

```
one two three
robin mike luke jennifer jessie
...
```

I've tried with:

```
cat file | sed -E 's/(.+ two|jennifer) .+/\1 /'
one two
robin mike luke jennifer
```

but I miss the next field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks as though you have access to GNU tools, I'd suggest using grep:

```
grep -Eo '.*\b(two|jennifer)(\s+\S+)?' file
```

This matches anything up to the field "two" or "jennifer", followed by the next field, if it exists. Thanks to [@123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923629/123) for useful suggestions.

`-o` only prints the matching part of the line and `-E` enables extended regular expressions.

Comment: Will match fields that contain two or jennifer. Edit will also fail if first or last field. Maybe `grep -oP '.*\b(two|jennifer)(\s\S+)?'`

Comment: I've edited again, thanks. I guess that `-P` isn't required though?

Comment: Nope, just habit of using it instead of `-E`!

Comment: It prints nothing if there is no match. Then again maybe that's desired?

Comment: @JamesBrown Easy fix if not `grep -Po '.*\b(two|jennifer)(\s+\S+)?|^.*'`

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a) NF=((i+1)>NF?NF:(i+1))} 1' pats ex
one two three
robin mike luke jennifer jessie
```

where `pats` is the pattern file and `ex` the example records file. Explained:

```
NR==FNR {                           # process pattern file
    a[$1]                           # store all patterns into a hash
    next                            # skip to next record
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)              # for each word in example file record
        if($i in a)                 # check if found in a
            NF=((i+1)>NF?NF:(i+1))  # if found, cut record after the next word
} 1                                 # print the record
```

Currently program checks if word is found in hash `a`. That means that while processing first record it checks it for `two` and `jennifer`. If that's not desirable, it can be handled easily by replacing

- second line: `a[$i]` to `a[FNR]=$1` and
- seventh line: `if($i in a)` to `if($i==a[FNR])`